# Adding a new bibliography style with R Markdown and TinyTex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, biblatex, tinytex

I'm writing a paper using R Markdown and TinyTex, using Biblatex for referencing. It works fine with default referencing styles, but I need to add a custom bibliography and citation style for the journal I'm writing for.

I need to follow the Unified Stylesheet for Linguistics, for which there is a Biblatex implementation available on Github [here](https://github.com/semprag/biblatex-sp-unified), containing a .bbx and .cbx file.

I've tried adding those .bbx and .cbx files to my local copy of TinyTex, inside `Library/TinyTex/texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex`. My YAML header includes:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
biblatexoptions: [bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified, citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]
```

When I knit the document, I get the following error:

```
tlmgr search --file --global '/biblatex-dm.cfg'
! Package keyval Error: bibstyle undefined.
```

I don't have a `biblatex-dm.cfg` file (nor do I really understand what that would be). I would have thought the .bbx and .cbx files would be sufficient, based on the regular installation instructions in the style's Github repo.

Where should I put .bbx and .cbx files, so that tlmgr can find them? And/or what additional steps do I need to take to use this style with my paper?

====================================================================

UPDATE: The problem seems to be coming from the Pandoc LaTeX template that R Markdown uses.

Setting aside R Markdown, I created a smaller minimal LaTeX example:

- main.tex
- references.bib

Where main.tex is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified,citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

Something something \citep{darwin_origin_1859}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And references.bib is:

```
@book{darwin_origin_1859,
    location = {London},
    title = {On the Origin of Species by Means of Natural Selection},
    publisher = {J. Murray},
    author = {Darwin, Charles},
    date = {1859}
}
```

I had success compiling this example using the sequence of commands `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`. Thus it seems my local TeX installation knows about the `biblatex-sp-unified.bbx` and `sp-authoryear-comp.cbx` files I added and can use them just fine.

Subsequently, I created an equivalent minimal R Markdown document with the YAML header:

```
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: references.bib
biblatexoptions: [bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified, citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]
```

and body:

```
Something something [@darwin_origin_1859].
```

This time, I got the same old error message from before:

```
tlmgr search --file --global '/biblatex-dm.cfg'
! Package keyval Error: bibstyle undefined.
```

This would seem to suggest that the problem is caused by something in Pandoc's LaTeX template, but I don't know what.

Just to confirm that it's definitely the Pandoc template and not my own installation/setup, I took the .tex file that gets produced when I knit the minimal R Markdown example above, and tried to compile it in Overleaf (with `biblatex-sp-unified.bbx` and `sp-authoryear-comp.cbx` files added). I reproduced the same error.

Although I think I've localised the problem, I'd still very much like to understand what and where the problem is in the Pandoc template. I'd also be keen to hear if anyone has any fixes (other than just using a different template or writing my own).

Comment: What is the output of `kpsewhich biblatex-sp-unified.bbx` in a terminal? I would try  `sudo mktexlsr`, if that does not return the path to the file.

Comment: `kpsewhich` returns `kpsewhich: command not found`. This is strange because tlmgr says kpathsea is already installed (`tlmgr install: package already present: kpathsea`). `which kpsewhich` returns `/usr/local/bin/kpsewhich` which is in `$PATH`.

Comment: Can you try with full path, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/kpsewhich biblatex-sp-unified.bbx`?

Comment: Thanks for your persistence on this! I tried with full path and the command worked (i.e. no error message) though didn't return any result. I ran `sudo mktexlsr` as suggested then tried again, but still no result. I noticed `mktexlsr` did not seem to update the `texmf-local` directory, which is where I saved the bbx and cbx files. It updated: `texmf-config/ls-R...`, `texmf-dist/ls-R...` and `texmf-var/ls-R...`

Maybe I should move the files to one of those three directories?

Comment: Upstream’s installation instructions suggest using `TEXMFHOME`. That has the advantage of not requiring an `ls-R` file. I would try that first. IIRC, `tinytex` the R package has a command for initialisation of `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've done some further digging and I don't think the problem is the location of the .bbx and .cbx files after all. I found I can use them with a minimal LaTeX example. It breaks when I try to use them with R Markdown though, which makes me think it's a problem with something in Pandoc's LaTeX template. I've updated my question with details of what I tried.

Comment: Which versions of `rmarkdown` and `pandoc` are you using? Your example works for me with version 2.1 and 2.7.3 respectively.

Comment: Ah yup, good point. Turns out I was using v2.2 of pandoc and v1.something of rmarkdown. My bad. I upgraded everything and the example works now for me too. More specifically, the YAML option `biblatexoptions` is being converted to the tex command `\usepackage[option1=option,...]{biblatex}` instead of the command `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{option1=option,...}` that it was producing previously.

Comment: I ended up updating R, Rstudio (which updates Pandoc) and all my packages. I also did a fresh re-install of tinytex. All seems to be working well now. Thanks very much for your helpful comments. If you post an answer just saying that it's an issue with packages being out of date, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think it makes more sense if you update your existing answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: This seems to be an issue with using an out-of-date version of R Markdown and/or Pandoc.**

I was using `rmarkdown` package v.1. At time of writing, the most up-to-date version is 2.1.

I updated all my packages and updated Rstudio (which currently ships with Pandoc v2.3.1) and no longer experience problems. I also upgraded R (from 3.5.something to 3.6.2) and did a fresh re-install of tinytex while I was at it, but I'm not sure whether those things had an effect for this particular problem.

Now, when I put `biblatexoptions: [bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified, citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]` in my YAML header, it's correctly converted into the LaTeX command `\usepackage[bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified,citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]{biblatex}`, rather than the `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` command as described below.

Ralf Stubner initially suggested I check my R Markdown/Pandoc versions in the comments. Please give his comments an upvote if you them useful as well.

---

**Problem recap:**

I'm writing a document in R Markdown and I have a particular referencing style that I'd like to use with biblatex. I have a `.bbx` and `.cbx` file defining the style, available on Github (linked above). The problem is that the document fails to compile, saying biblio/citation styles are undefined (even when the style files are in the project folder itself).

I've found that the problem was caused by the way I was passing options to biblatex. In my YAML Header, the line:

`biblatexoptions: [bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified, citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]`

gets converted to the latex command:

`\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified,citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp}`

I'm not sure why, but when this command is included, it produces the errors I was observing.

**Installing new Biblatex style:**

I'm finding that TeX doesn't know about the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files when they're in my `~/Library/TinyTex/texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex` directory (which is where I expected to put them based on the Github installation instructions).

To get the referencing style recognised by the system, I placed `.bbx` and `.cbx` files inside `~/Library/TinyTex/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx` and `~/Library/TinyTex/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx` respectively. Then, in the terminal, I ran `sudo mktexlsr`.

(Alternatively, for use only with a particular document, the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files could simply be kept in the project directory with the R Markdown file)

**Original hacky answer (but see update above):**

Instead of using `biblatexoptions` in the YAML header of the R Markdown document, I simply knitted it with `citation_package: biblatex` (and no extra options). I also added `keep_tex: yes`. Then, I opened the resulting tex file, found the `\usepackage{bibtex}` command and added the desired options, so it read `\usepackage[bibstyle=biblatex-sp-unified,citestyle=sp-authoryear-comp]{biblatex}`.

Finally, I ran `pdflatex` and `biber` on the tex file in the terminal. Clearly far from ideal, but it will technically produce the desired output.